# Weird space issue in nested tables

Tags: html

I'm trying to troubleshoot a fairly simple page which has a nested table in it and gives me an unwanted horizontal space for some reason. I removed most of the code until all I'm left with are the tables and the space still exists.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ‎<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        a
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can get around this using divs but I'm wondering if someone could explain this to me, I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jeo3ya9n/

Inspecting the DOM in IE shows me an empty line between the first TD and the table, inspecting in Chrome shows me:

```
"
    &lrm;"
```

at the same spot. Deleting those removes the unwanted space but I'm not seeing what causes them in the code.

Comment: I believe the `table` element has a _margin_ or a _padding_ by default. I'm not sure though. And my guess is that the browsers just interpret it their way.

Comment: Firefox doesn't do it but I can reproduce this in Chrome. Seems strange. If you nest a table again the `&ltr;` only occurs between the first and second table. Browser bug?

Comment: wow... this is true, but can't find **anything** on the net about this!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many of IE's layout bugs, which are irritating to fix.Few suggestions:

***1)*** Set the containing cell's padding-top to 0em

***2)*** Set the nested table's margin-top to 0em